# Validation on EditText from outside BaseAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have list box that consist EditBox in each row of listbox. On button Save I have to check is all EditText object filled with data or not.

This is how is constructed adapter for ListView:

```
public class LvAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<PList> arrayPList;

    public LvAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<PList> array) {
         context = mContext;
         activity = (Activity) context;
         arrayPreStart = array;
    }       

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayPList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arrayPList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_prestartcheck_list, null);
        viewHolder.edComment = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edComment);
        viewHolder.edComment.setTag(position);
        return convertView;
    }
   }

public class ViewHolder {
        EditText edComment;
}
```

Define one custom method in main class to check for any empty EditText :
MainClass.java:

```
ListView lvQuestion;
ArrayList<PList> arrayPList = new ArrayList<>();
PList pList = new PList();
btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            boolean isAnyEmpty=true;
            for (int i=0; i<arrayPList.size(); i++) {
                 View view =  lvQuestion.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
                 EditText quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edComment);
                quantity.requestFocus(); 
                quantity.setError("asdasda");
                isAnyEmpty=false;
                break;
            }
        });
}
```

I have test the object by using setText and working fine for me but only requestfocus and setError not working, please help to figure out this or give me alternate solution

Comment: just check you edittext inside your getview(); by position

Comment: but I have a button in different view that's why I use this function for empty checking, I will use this function against button click listener.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a condition to check if any of the `EditText` is empty.

Change your method like this

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
    boolean isAnyEmpty=false;
    for (int i=0;i<quantityCheckList.size();i++){
        View view =  lvQuestion.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        EditText quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
        if(quantity.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            quantity.requestFocus(); 
            quantity.setError("asdasda");
            isAnyEmpty=true;
            break;
        }
   }
   return isAnyEmpty;
}
```

Comment: the code is working fine bro, only issue i am facing requestFocus();  not work if I use quantity.setText("asdasda"); code working fine for particular EditText

Comment: Without the if condition `requestFocus` is called for every `EditText` which is blank.